# Generating CSS Class (With Unique Name) Dynamically Using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Is it possible to generate a CSS class with a name and then apply it to certain DOM objects using Angular? I am aware of `ng-style` and other directives. However, it seems that they focus on toggling existing classes or just adding CSS properties to a DOM.

What I am trying to do is pull out some values from database, pass them to a unique CSS class as property values and then apply the class to certain DOM objects.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by *"pass them to a unique CSS class"*?

Comment: what css properties are you persisting in a database?

Comment: @mrtig mostly hex color values. However, if I can figure this out, I may add some other customizations later. For now, just hex strings.

Comment: @developer033 What I mean is that I have a calendar that allows customization of certain entries by passing the name of a custom CSS class in JSON to it. What I was trying to do is create several custom CSS classes dynamically, each with their own property values and then pass appropriate classes with entries to the calendar. This would solve my entry-customization problem. Otherwise, I am looking at modifying the calendar, but that seems like a doozie at the moment.

Comment: I surmise that if I can figure out how to dynamically generate a new CSS class from Angular, that would move me towards my goal.

Comment: I would like to help... but I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Without a JSFiddle to see, I can't really help.

Comment: @frosty What is not clear? How can I give you a JSFIddle if I do not know how to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can append some value to the end of a string that acts as your class base. On your UI element, do something like

```
<div class="my-base-class-name-{{myScopeVar}}"></div>
```

Then you can define all the possible combinations in your stylesheets. Let me know if this answer needs refining based on more input about your problem.